# Appium | How can I change language on API 24 or higer emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, appium, appium-android

I set these capabilities for AVD in my code.

AND 6.0.0 API 23:

```
capabilities.SetCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.Avd, “AND_6.0.0_1080x1920_4.95in”);
capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, “Android”);
capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, “AND_6.0.0_1080x1920_4.95in”);
capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, “6.0”);
capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.Language, Session.Language);
capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.Locale, Session.Locale);
capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, app);
```

AND 7.0.0 API 24:

```
capabilities.SetCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.Avd, “AND_7.0.0_1080x1920_4.95in”);
capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, “Android”);
capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, “AND_7.0.0_1080x1920_4.95in”);
capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, “7.0”);
capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.Language, Session.Language);
capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.Locale, Session.Locale);
capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, app);
```

Language is “cs” or “en” and Locale is “CZ” or “US”.

When I running tests on AND 6.0.0 I can change language on every start, but on AND 7.0.0 is language everytime set to english.

Please, where is problem? I want to change language also on AND 7.0.0. I have also capabilities for AND 5 and 4 and its working, but on AND 7 and 8 its not working.

Comment: Your Appium version?

Comment: newest v1.7.2 server and 3.0.0.2 WebDriver

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you faced [change locale on SDK 24+ with appium 1.7.2](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9944) issue

As a workaround, you have 2 options:

1. Downgrade appium server to **1.7.1** (no issue there): `npm install -g appium@1.7.1`
2. Wait for next beta release: Fix already been made in `appium-android-driver` 1.37.1, so my guess it will be in **1.7.3-beta** for sure.